# Tips and gotchas when developing with multiple Apple IDs

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm in charge of developing and submitting the apps to the app store as the clients have sent us their apple logins. As far as developing the apps, that's been OK (I haven't submitted any yet) but in the next week I will need to submit at least three, all with different Apple IDs.

I've removed the Xcode password from the keychain and synced my certificates to the second Apple ID I have. Oh god, the mess it made with my keys, and profiles. When I did this with my own Apple Id (Xcode 3) I had to do the whole thing manually and could name keys, etc like I wanted. I entered the second Apple Id (Xcode 4) and now Xcode want's to manage everything for me. I like this but it created the keys and profiles with some stupid names. It makes it very difficult for me to sign apps with one or the other and also to backup one client's keys and not confuse them with mine. I'm afraid to enter the third Apple Id because I know the mess will be impossible to handle.

I'm open to tips, gotchas to look out for when working with multiple Apple IDs so that I can know "how it's done". And also, any other things along the way that I might encounter in the submission progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier if you use a separate user account on OS X for each client.

If you use one shared account for everything, then there shouldn't be any conflict if you only have one developer key and use separate bundle IDs for each application.  The signing works backwards from the bundle ID - from the bundle ID it finds the correct provisioning profile, and from the provisioning profile it finds the correct distribution key.

Comment: For @Julian, if you're a (save to desktop junkie) like I am, using separate user accounts can also be very beneficial for keeping track of saved application resources like images, sounds, etc..

Comment: @Jim, I don't know about the different profiles. It just doesn't feel right having to go through the hassle of creating the profile, configuring the software for each profile, etc, etc (most of the apps I do work with a php backend so I need to change the settings on the FTP client, github account, ssh_config, etc, etc). How about private key names. Being this such a common scenario (same guy, multiple clients) Do you know how to keep track of those easily? The last pair that Xcode generated were just called "<key>"! I wonder how it's going to call the next pair I create!

Comment: You can automate setting up a new account fairly easily.  Just set up your software on a clean account then copy over any relevant Library contents to each new account.  You can rename keys in Keychain Access, but if you've only got the keys for one developer account per OS X account, it's not that big of a deal because the keychains are separate.